# Задать ComboBox SelectedItem и сделать его ReadOnly

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox Name="MyBox" SelectedIndex="0" FontSize="20">
    <ComboBoxItem>-</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Вот как он заполняется:

```
public void FillComboBox()
{
    foreach (var res in list)
        MyBox.Items.Add(res.Name);
}
```

Нужно, чтобы при открытии окна свойство SelectedItem в ComboBox было item с Name="Ivan". Плюс сделать ComboBox ReadOnly. Т.е. так, чтобы из него нельзя было ничего выбрать.

Comment: Что вы сами пробовали? Задавали сами SelectedItem? Нашли свойство ReadOnly?

Comment: Я пробовал присвоить SelectedItem таким способом: MyBox.SelectedItem.Equals(index);, где index - полученный индекс list через лямбда выражения. Но всё равно ничего не присваивается. А свойство IsReadOnly программно вот так: MyBox.IsReadOnly = true; почему то не работает

Comment: [подсказка :) с примерами](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.combobox(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: `MyBox.SelectedItem.Equals(index)` - это определенно не похоже на присвоение.

Comment: С присвоением разобрался. Как программно сделать IsReadOnly ComboBox-а true? Почему так не работает: StationsBox.IsReadOnly = true;?

Comment: `DropDownStyle.DropDownList`

Comment: Как это сделать программно, обращаясь к названию ComboBox?

Comment: `Почему так не работает: StationsBox.IsReadOnly = true;?` что значит не работает? Вы после этого можете выбрать любой элемент в комбобоксе?

Comment: В общем, чтобы заблочить весь комбобокс, укажите `cb.IsEnabled = false;`. Поля `IsReadOnly` и `IsEditable` относятся к возможности писать текст в комбобокс, и не трогают возможность выбрать какой либо элемент.

Comment: Можно узнать зачем нужен `ComboBox` без возможности выбора?